# unable to read pdf file using imagick

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a pdf file to a jpeg. But I cant even get the simplest example to work.

```
    <?php
if (!extension_loaded('imagick'))
    die('Imagick is not installed');
else
    echo 'Imagick installed<hr>';

$inputFile="test.pdf";
if(file_exists($inputFile)){
    echo "$inputFile exists.<br>";
}
else{
    die("$inputFile doesnt exist.");
}
$imagick = new Imagick(); 
$imagick->readImage($inputFile); 
$imagick = $imagick->flattenImages(); 
$imagick->writeFile('test.jpg'); 
?>
```

The first test says the file exists but imagaick is not able to read the file.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 
'unable to open image `test.pdf': No such file or directory @ 
 error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2646' in C:\xampp\htdocs\img\index.php:14 Stack trace: #0 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\img\index.php(14): Imagick->__construct('test.pdf') #1 {main} thrown in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\img\index.php on line 14
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Doesn't it tell you all you need to know? `unable to open image 'test.pdf': No such file or directory`

Comment: index.php and test.pdf are placed together in the same folder.

Comment: @BenM in the file exists check before that the file is detected successfully. So the file does exist and is accessible by the php code. :/

Comment: Try : `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/your/file/test.pdf'`

Comment: @Brewal $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$inputFile still the same error. I'm running this on xampp on windows. It can't be a permissions issue can it ?

Comment: Is it possible that my installation of imagick is corrupted or something ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your path to pdf file,
simply use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

```
$inputFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test.pdf";
```